# Lost my job, health insurance too? (European citizen living in Denmark)

Tags: health-insurance, denmark

I lost my job working in DK as an expat. They gave me a 3-month notice while I still get paid. When those 3 months end, do I still have health insurance?

I've been working for a bit over 2 years, I got the yellow insurance card.

Comment: In Germany (hence comment, not answer), the Bundesagentur für Arbeit pays your health insurance while you are unemployed.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are a legal resident you will have health insurance.

https://www.borger.dk/sundhed-og-sygdom/Sygesikring-og-laegevalg/Sygesikring-for-udlaendinge-i-Danmark

> Enhver person, der har bopæl i Danmark (dvs. er tilmeldt folkeregistret), har ret til alle offentlige sundhedsydelser.

My translation:
"Every person who has residence in Denmark (that is, is registered in the central person register) has right to all public health services."